# How to deal with 2 opened windows?

Tags: python, browser, tabs, pywinauto

This code is capable of finding open browser windows and closing all tabs separately. When the user has 2 same opened windows (for example: "YouTube - Opera") it spawns an error at `app.connect(title=BrowserTitle)`. How can I count if the window is opened more than once and if yes could connect on only one?

```py
for browser in BrowserWindows:
    
    #searching only for Opera Browser 
    if(browser.find("Opera")):        
        #Browser title is fulfilled from for loop
        BrowserTitle = browser
        app = Application(backend='uia')
        app.connect(title=BrowserTitle)

        #printing out URL
        element_name = "Adresové pole"
        dlg = app.top_window()
        dlg.click_input()
        #url = dlg.child_window(title=element_name, control_type="Edit").get_value()
        #print(url)
        #změna záložky pro vypsání více url
        wrapper_list = dlg.descendants(control_type="TabItem")

        time.sleep(2)
        app.wait_cpu_usage_lower()
```